# Rails 4 Query Performance & Moving Queries out of View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, query-performance

I fairly new to some aspects of rails and have a query in my view thats really slowing down my response time. I'm sure some rails experts can slap me around on this one.

Model **Company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, inverse_of: :company
  has_many :projects, inverse_of: :company
end
```

Controller **companies_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @companies = Company.all.includes(:contacts, :projects)
end
```

View **index.html.rb**
(edit) What I'm doing here is getting the sum of `:material_total_weight_lbs` from all the projects that belong to a specific company.

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <td>
    <%=  
      number_with_delimiter(
        @companies.where(id: company.id).sum(:material_total_weight_lbs)
      ) 
    %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

`:material_total_weight_lbs` is a project attribute.

My rails server output looks like this...

```
...  
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 511]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT SUM(material_total_weight_lbs) FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts" ON "contacts"."company_id" = "companies"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  [["id", 511]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 512]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT SUM(material_total_weight_lbs) FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts" ON "contacts"."company_id" = "companies"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  [["id", 512]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 513]]
   (1.2ms)  SELECT SUM(material_total_weight_lbs) FROM "companies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts" ON "contacts"."company_id" = "companies"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  [["id", 513]]
  Rendered companies/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3454.9ms)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "companies"
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" WHERE (scheduled_start_date > '2015-01-22 15:25:07.717772')
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "materials"
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_topnavbar.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3509ms (Views: 2664.9ms | ActiveRecord: 843.6ms)
```

Questions
1. What is the best practice for moving this logic out of the view?
2. How do I setup this query to have the best performance?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're trying to do here.

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <td>
    <%=  
      number_with_delimiter(
        @companies.where(id: company.id).sum(:material_total_weight_lbs)
      ) 
    %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

I think this should simply be

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <td>
    <%=  
      number_with_delimiter(
        company.material_total_weight_lbs
      ) 
    %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Companies have many projects. material_total_weight_lbs is an attribute of project. So I am totaling all the material_total_wieght_lbs from all the projects that belong to a specific company.

Answer (score 0):

Since the material_total_weight_lbs attribute is in the project, and company has_many projects, so you should try to fetch it from there.

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>   <td>
    <%=  
      number_with_delimiter(
        company.projects.sum(:material_total_weight_lbs)
      ) 
    %>   </td> <% end %>
```

Performance is slow because inside each loop you are using @companies again, resulting in the execution of multiple queries. Ideal way is to create scopes or you can also use decorators to clear out your views.

Comment: Thankyou for the help.  I tried this and it does reduce the amount of joining done but the number of queries is the same and it took the same amount of time. I will check out scopes.

Comment: The count queries have nothing to do with the code above. You might be using count some where. You can also try collect which return the collection.

Comment: Im thinking it would be best to add a column like total_lbs_processed to the companies table then when I save, update, or delete a project call a function that computes the total :material_total_weight_lbs of all the projects belonging to the company and updates the appropriate column on the company table.